# faster method for sorting data smallest to largest using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I use the following code to sort the data in worksheet cells ,but for large amount of data ,it takes a lot of time. Is there any other method to do it more faster?

the used code is:

```
Sub VBA_DataSorting()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim temp As Double ' must be double to contain fractional values
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion 'Range of data to be sorted
For i = 1 To rng.count
    For j = i + 1 To rng.count
    If rng.Cells(j) < rng.Cells(i) Then  ' sort smallest to largest
    'swap numbers
    temp = rng.Cells(i)
    rng.Cells(i) = rng.Cells(j)
    rng.Cells(j) = temp
    End If
Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Why aren't you using the built in sort function from the tool bar?

Comment: @Scott Craner i want to use VBA macro, not manullay

Comment: Then use the `range.sort` method.

Comment: bubble sorting for ranges is not wise when there's a built in function for that. What you are doing may be applicable for arrays. I personally still experienced that writing to a range within a temp sheet, sorting that range and writing back to the array is also faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
sub SortDataExample()

 'Building data to sort on the active sheet.
 Range("A1").Value = "Name"
 Range("A2").Value = "Bill"
 Range("A3").Value = "Rod"
 Range("A4").Value = "John"
 Range("A5").Value = "Paddy"
 Range("A6").Value = "Kelly"
 Range("A7").Value = "William"
 Range("A8").Value = "Janet"
 Range("A9").Value = "Florence"
 Range("A10").Value = "Albert"
 Range("A11").Value = "Mary"
 MsgBox "The list is out of order. Hit Ok to continue...", vbInformation

 'Selecting a cell within the range.
 Range("A2").Select

 'Applying sort.
 With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Sort
 .SortFields.Clear
 .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:A11"), _
 SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
 .SetRange Range("A1:A11")
 .Header = xlYes
 .MatchCase = False
 .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
 .SortMethod = xlPinYin
 .Apply
 End With
 MsgBox "Sort complete.", vbInformation

End Sub
```